# How to implement a custom authentication mechanism for a WCF Web Service

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, custom-authentication

I have just created my first WCF service. Now I would like to do the following:

1. Add my custom authentication mechanism, e.g., querying a database's user table.
2. Make the results of my service's operations dependent on the user that has logged in.

How do I do that?

NOTE: I have already tried googling, even using site filters such as "site:stackoverflow.com" and "site:codeproject.com", but couldn't find what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greetings,

Depending on the size of the project, some of the solutions outlined in the link below may be overkill, however, feel free to take a look.

[WCF Security Practices](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20Tos&ProjectName=wcfsecurity)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UserNamePasswordValidator and override the Validate method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx

Inside your service implementation you'll have access to "OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity" which is the user that was authenticated.

Comment: also, make sure you check "IsAuthenticated" to make sure the user is authenticated.